# Tag a row based on aggregate value condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping, aggregation

Here is my dataset, where order is the fix sequence of each product.

[image: Initial data set]

What I want is another column in here, lets say `TagID`. `TagID` is an `int` value that will based on the aggregate Count column, group it by product if it is greater or equal to 5.

So the dataset would look like this:

[image: Desired results]

How can I accomplish this in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not quite getting the logic, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Charlieface, I need to group the records based on the aggregate count. group it by product if it is greater or equal to 5

Comment: @DaleK I tried to use the formatted text but it ended with a single line, without any spacing.  Please assist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Sorry still not clear: first group based on `Product` then aggregate, then calculate `TagId` how? Or do you mean to do a running sum and aggregate on that somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a recursive CTE.  You already have a numbering column, so this is pretty simple:

```
with cte as (
      select product, order, count, 1 as grp, count as s
      from t
      where order = 1
      union all
      select cte.product. t.order, t.count,
             (case when cte.s + t.count >= 5 then grp + 1 else grp end),
             (case when cte.s + t.count >= 5 then t.count else cte.s + t.count end)
      from cte join
           t
           on t.product = cte.product and t.order = cte.order + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```